# Software for editing EXIF data

Tags: metadata, software-recommendation, picasa

Can someone please recommend software that enables editing for exposure mode EXIF data?

I have tried with Picasa, but it doesn't support editing of this specific property.

Comment: I'm just wondering why would you would want to edit that? It indicates what exposure mode the camera was using when taking the picture, so normally it doesn't make any sense to change that.

Comment: @Guffa (and grm): I was asking myself the same question!

Comment: I think he wants to cheat.

Comment: Yea, wanted to cheat on an assignment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jhead is a capable tool for modifying and examining exif data.
[See this link](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/)

Answer (score 9):

Probably the most likely option is [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) as it seems to be the Swiss Army Knife of editors, though not the easiest for people to use.

Comment: Thanks. Only the commercial version had this option though.

Comment: @grm are you kidding? exiftool is free.

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Works with `exiftool -exposuremode="Manual" input.jpg`