# How to remove orientation attribute from the photo without touching other exif-data?

Tags: metadata, windows, image-orientation

Removing exif-data via Windows file properties does not allow to delete only orientation attribute and removing all exif data removes GPS position also.

Is there any way to remove only the orientation attribute leaving other exif data intact?

Comment: Have you done even a cursory search on this site for the term "edit EXIF?"

Comment: Yes, but found nothing

Comment: I found 170+ results, at least a couple of dozen that are at least somewhat related to the basic question "how to edit EXIF data."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a software that make it possible to edit all exif values and add new paramerers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/is-there-a-software-that-make-it-possible-to-edit-all-exif-values-and-add-new-pa)

Comment: Related: [Adding data to an EXIF file](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1177/15871) and [Software for editing EXIF data](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3268/15871) and [Are there GIMP plugins that allow one to view and edit EXIF data?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1512/15871) and [Updating metadata in Darktable](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90088/15871) and [How can I strip tags from a JPEG without removing the color profile?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56378/15871)

Comment: See also: [If an image is rotated losslessly, why does the file size change?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84292/15871)

Comment: Instead of removing the orientation tag, it may be more useful to set it to 1. ie to specify the image is not rotated.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to remove the orientation tag:

```
exiftool -Orientation= /target/dir/or/File
```

Replace `/target/dir/or/File` with the files and/or directories you want to process. If run under Unix/Mac, use single quotes to avoid `bash` interpretation.

- To suppress the creation of backup files, add `-overwrite_original`.
- To recurse into subdirectories, add `-r`.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the mentioned *exiftool* command did not work for me. It rewrote the metadata, but did not remove the Orientation tag. I finally found this solution:

```
exiftool -n -Orientation=0 /path/to/my/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer: Rotate photo on Windows File Explorer. 
Orientation attribute is removed during rotation but all other exif-data is remaining in the photo.

Comment: Who knows how Windows will mangle the data? ... But maybe it's okay... [Are “Windows Photo Viewer” rotations lossless?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/12362/75526)

Comment: Wait, what? If I tell File Explorer to rotate my image, it will delete the rotation tag? A) It does not (tried it just now, IrfanView now rotates the picture as I told File Explorer before), B) if it did, this would be a major bug in the rotation routine and I wouldn't count on it being there forever.